# How to build angular 2 app without cli

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, production, angular2-build

I am new in angular 2, I want to know how to build my angular 2 app without using CLI for production.

**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: what do you mean by without

Comment: I mean without Angular CLi. with angular cli command ng build --prod which do i want same thing without it.

Comment: You don't want to use the CLI at all, or just for production?

Comment: Thanks for replay, I do not want use  in my project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have used  CLI for your existing application You can migrate from Angular CLI to Webpack and tweak it accordingly for
 (local, development, production).
Since Angular CLI v1.0 there’s the “eject” feature, that allows you to extract the`webpack` config file and manipulate it as you wish.

Run `ng eject` so Angular CLI generates the webpack.config.js file.
Run `npm install` so the new dependencies generated by CLI are satisfied
Refer this [Angular CLI to webpack](https://medium.com/@s2dent/from-angular-cli-to-webpack-2-and-other-production-solutions-with-examples-f127abe06842)
if you don't want to use CLI at all Refer This [An Angular 2 Webpack setup for development and production](https://hackernoon.com/an-angular-2-webpack-setup-for-development-and-production-3ea8bcc35e24) and [Webpack: An Introduction](https://angular.io/guide/webpack#webpack-an-introduction)

Comment: Thanks Vikas, I think this can help.

Comment: You're welcome!! Can you make it as correct answer if that's what you were looking for?

Comment: Note that to use eject you have to use the version 1.7 of the CLI

Comment: Sadly, this answer is no longer correct since the eject feature has been removed long ago. I do not know an easy way to do this yet, it seems the Angular team is solely focused on Angular CLI and Bazel right now.

Comment: I have included a second link too where you can use webpack config, I will modify the answer soon

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go without Angular CLI

1. Do create all the required thing by yourself, and that is very difficult task
2. you should go here : https://github.com/angular/quickstart , download quickstart project and start work

But I strongly suggest go with CLI as there it support end to end activity i.e. project start till deployment project

Comment: For Some region I do not want to use angular 2 cli, I am doing the which you suggest but problem is I want to build it for production, in angular 2 official doc using cli to build it (ng build --prod)